# How to find a file with specific content?

Tags: python

I have file with this content:

```
Sent
Trash
Drafts
Junk
```

and I want to find and delete it with Python.

I know the loop to search files and open the file and I know how regular expressions work, but regex reads files line by line and I can't just search with the key words because there are many files that contain these words (like `'Send'`) and I want the exact content. What can I do?

I thought something like this:

```
with open(fullsourcefilename) as openfile:
   if openfile.read() == "Sent\nTrash\nDrafts\nJunk":
```

but it don't work.

Comment: I think there is probably an extra newline character at the end that you are missing- also use `.read()` on the file.

Comment: @AlexThornton i add read() but it pass the condition.

Comment: Have you checked my answer with the extra newline character?

Comment: @AlexThornton yes sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a multiline regex:

```
import re

with open(fullsourcefilename) as openfile:
   if re.search(r'Sent\nTrash\nDrafts\nJunk\n', openfile.read(), re.MULTILINE):
```

This is not the most optimal check if you have large files, but works if all you need is a quick and dirty solution.